# jeditable how to save entire row to a file

Tags: tablesorter, jeditable

I am using table sorter and JEditable plugins.

The table's  last column is editable to enable the user to do some on the fly data curations.
My question is when the user edits last column using jeditable's standard code, how do I save that cell's entire row values in to a file?

Please help,
Apallav

Comment: Maybe try out the editable widget instead of JEditable. [This demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-editable.html) provides an example on how to interact with your server using the `editComplete` event.

Comment: Mottie, can you give an example? I have like 20 columns in a table in the "tabs". I should be able to edit the 20th column alone but would want to get the entire row values passed to a php script - dont know how to achieve this.